# Adding items to multiple tables with linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, list

Let's say I have two tables one called Customers and one called CustomerAddresses.  Then lets say I have a Customer object which contains a property that is of the type `List<Address>`.  This property holds a list of all the different shipping addresses a customer may have used, so it could contain 0 - n addresses in it (just one string with the whole address for simplicity sake).  Now I have a collection of Customer objects which I want to load into these two tables with a linq to sql procedure.  The Customers table has a column called CustomerID which is an identity column and should auto-increment.  The CustomerAddresses table has a column called CustomerID (and a column called Address as well) which connects the customers to the address(es) in the table.  I think my main difficulty here is figuring out how to add a List to the Tables and have the CustomerID columns match up.

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. I named CustomerAddresses the property you have in your customer object and holds the list of addresses.

```
static void SaveCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    using(var dc = new TestDC())
    {
        dc.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer);
        dc.SubmitChanges();

        foreach (CustomerAddress address in customer.CustomerAddresses)
        {
            address.CustomerId = customer.Id;
            dc.CustomerAddresses.InsertOnSubmit(address);
            dc.SubmitChanges()
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, you should put a FK between these tables, although it's not compulsory.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need.  I'll try it out and add any questions that might come up.  Thanks again.

Bob

Comment: no need to two SubmitChanges after foreach  dc.SubmitChanges() Apply all ID

Answer (score 2):

You add the customer rows (InsertOnSumbit), then activate the SubmitChanges() function which updates the customer objects you inserted with a newly generated ID.

```
using(var dc = new TestDC())
{
    var cust = new Customer();

    cust.Name = "Jack";

    dc.InsertOnSubmit(cust);

    SubmitChanges();  //  cust.Id will be updated with a new generated value
}
```

BTW, You can surround this code with TransactionScope for transactional support.

Enjoy.

Comment: How does linq to sql know which column to put the list of address strings into in the other table?  Does there need to be a foreign key set up between the two tables?

Comment: My example consists of adding a new row to identity-oriented table. You shouldn't represent list as a column type on SQL, thus not allowing it in LINQ as well. You should have a BL object called CustomerBL which will be populated by 2 tables (Customer & CustomerAddresses). CustomerBL will consist a list of addresses that can be filled from CustomerAddresses table (its columns will be: CustomerAddressId (PK int), CustomerId (PK int), Address (string)).

Comment: Maybe my problem is the setup of these tables and the business layer objects.